The Euthyphro and Natural Law
I'm interested in the Euthyphro dilemma and its treatment by various Christian thinkers. I'm familiar with Divine Command Theory and I was wondering: Is there a distinctive response from the tradition of Natural Law?

IEP discusses Responses to the Euthyphro Dilemma, including by Christian theologians. See also Answering the Euthyphro Dilemma with C.S. Lewis and Cornelius Van Til for a debate between two modern Christian apologists. Natural law proponents, like Aquinas, typically raise the impossible choice between arbitrariness of morality and its independence of God as a reason to give up the divine command theory.
